# Copy value of column where associated column partially matches another column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

My title is badly described as I am unable to describe it in one sentence.

I have Column A with a label and Column B showing its associated value.

I then have column C which is another label that **could** partially match Column A.

If there is a partial match, I want column F to show which label from Column C partially matches and then change its value to match the value in Column B and display the new value in Column G.

Sounds confusing but you can see from my image what I'm trying to achieve in Column G. The only bit I want to be achieved automatically is Column G to find the matches.

[image: Example using colours]

Comment: I voted to close: if you can't explain in words, how do you expect us to put effort in coding?

Comment: But the screenshot says it all - no?

Comment: Looks like `SUMIF()` is what you need

Comment: "find matches" not sum - otherwisewhy not aveageifs or minifs or maxifs - anywas, seems to have pleased OP - ta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per screenshot:

```
=INDEX(B2:B10,MATCH(LEFT(G2#,8),A2:A10,0))
```

[image: Outcome]